# Not able to create an instance of a class

Tags: asp.net

In a Project I have different modules or folders.In a module I have a namespace called idsobject.I have class in this namespace.

In another CS  fle in the same folder I'm trying to access this class.But i'm not able.while if put that cs  file in aPP_code than i able to get that class.

how to access the class in another cs file within the same folder.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post an example of the classes involved. Are the classes private?

Comment: no sir  class' are public.

but now its done.

Thnkx

Comment: but realy dont know waht was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In an ASP.NET web site project, *.cs files are only compiled and made available to the rest of the application if they're located in the App_Code folder, or a subfolder in App_Code, or if they are associated with a *.aspx as code behind.  The architecture is intended to allow full server-side compilation.  You can't just put a *.cs anywhere and expect IIS to be able to find it, compile it, and link it with the rest of the app.

With an ASP.NET web application, you can put *.cs files where ever you want, because they are compiled by Visual Studio using details that are kept in the project file.

I'm guessing that you're using a web site project, which is why it works when you put the file in App_Code.

Answer (score 0):

First check the namespace. If you accessing the correct namespace  then perhaps the class access is set to private.

You could give us some extra information.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds strange. Putting a class in a file in a Web project with a .cs extension should work just fine no matter which folder the file is located.

The only thing I can suggest is to make sure that there is at least a

```
using idsobject;
```

line at the top of the code unit where you are trying to access the class. The default behaviour for ASP.NET Web forms is for no namespace to be defined, which can sometimes lead to confusion.

Comment: Sir I'v included the naespace in my CS file.Still it does not show the class name in the intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

The class should be marked as `public` if you've tried to access it from another namespace.

If it doesn't help, please post here a problematic code snippet.